# My Azure sidekiq process is terminating right after starting?

Tags: azure, sidekiq

I have been using Azure containers for my project. I'm using different containers for the backend app and frontend. I have created a sidekiq process enclosed in the radis cache server on Azure. As I trigger a task to run the sidekiq process, the sidekiq container is not processing jobs/task